# Merge maps with recursive nested maps in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I would like to know if someone have an easy way to merge 2 deep nested maps together ?

For instance, I would like to get :

```
[
    "a" : "1",
    "animals" : ["cat" : "blue"]
] + [
    "b" : 2,
    "animals" : ["dog" : "red"]
] == [
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 2,
    "animals" : [
        "cat" : "blue",
        "dog" : "red"]
]
```

There is someone having easy solution ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can write one for `Map` using recursion:

```
Map.metaClass.addNested = { Map rhs ->
    def lhs = delegate
    rhs.each { k, v -> lhs[k] = lhs[k] in Map ? lhs[k].addNested(v) : v }   
    lhs
}

def map1 = [
    "a" : "1",
    "animals" : ["cat" : "blue"]
]

def map2 = [
    "b" : 2,
    "animals" : ["dog" : "red"]
]

assert map1.addNested( map2 ) == [
    a: '1', 
    animals: [cat: 'blue', dog: 'red'], 
    b: 2
]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this response is so far the simplest and the grooviest :)

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar solution as @dmahapatro, but with a method with variable arguments:

```
def m1 = [a: 1, animals: [cat: 'blue']]
def m2 = [b: 2, animals: [dog: 'red']]

Map merge(Map... maps) {
    Map result

    if (maps.length == 0) {
        result = [:]
    } else if (maps.length == 1) {
        result = maps[0]
    } else {
        result = [:]
        maps.each { map ->
            map.each { k, v ->
                result[k] = result[k] instanceof Map ? merge(result[k], v) : v
            }
        }
    }

    result
}

assert [:] == merge()
assert m1 == merge(m1)
assert [a:1, b:2, animals:[cat:'blue', dog:'red']] == merge(m1, m2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution similar to @dmahapatro, but without using metaClass:

```
Map mergeMaps(Map lhs, Map rhs) {
    rhs.each { k, v ->
        lhs[k] = (lhs[k] in Map ? mergeMaps(lhs[k], v) : v)
    }
    return lhs
}

def m1 = [a: 1, animals: [cat: 'blue']]
def m2 = [b: 2, animals: [dog: 'red']]

mergeMaps(m1, m2)
println(m1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very short, concise way of doing it without using the meta-programming:

```
Map one = ["a" : "1", "animals" : ["cat" : "blue"] ]
Map two = ["b" : "2", "animals" : ["dog" : "red"] ]

Map three = [:]
(one.entrySet() + two.entrySet()).each { entry -> 
    three[entry.key] = three.containsKey(entry.key) ? [:] << three[entry.key] << entry.value : entry.value 
}

println three
```

Renders the output:

```
 [a:1, animals:[cat:blue, dog:red], b:2]
```

Comment: Does this handle an arbitrary level of nesting? For example, would it work if Map one and Map two both contained an array "primates" as an element within "animals", where "primates" contains different entries for Map one and Map two?