# Groovy map merge

Tags: groovy

**Question:**
How can I merge two groovy maps with same set of keys but different values.

Example:

```
Map one = [ 'a': ['foot':'ball'],
            'b': 'cricket',
            'c': 'tennis'
           ]

Map two = ['a': ['basket':'ball']]
```

What I want the output to be is:

```
Map three = [ 'a': ['foot':'ball', 
                    'basket': 'ball'],
                'b': 'cricket',
                'c': 'tennis'
               ]
```

So as seen above, it needs to pick any matching keys and merge the values of those keys and result in the combined map.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to deal with collisions, e.g., 'foot' mapped to 'hand' in one of the maps?

Comment: if foot mapped to hand, then the latter takes precedence. So Map two takes precedence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge maps with recursive nested maps in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475111/merge-maps-with-recursive-nested-maps-in-groovy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a slightly shorter way to do this, but it's pretty concise:

```
   Map three = [:]
   (one.entrySet() + two.entrySet()).each { entry -> 
       three[entry.key] = three.containsKey(entry.key) ? [:] << three[entry.key] << entry.value : entry.value 
   }

   println three
```

And yields the desired result:

```
[a:[foot:ball, basket:ball], b:cricket, c:tennis]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the shortest, but a good way to merge maps:

```
Map merge(Map left, Map right) {
    [right.findAll { k, _ -> !left.containsKey(k) },
     left.findAll { k, _ -> !right.containsKey(k) },
     left.findAll { k, _ -> right.containsKey(k) }
             .collectEntries { k, v -> [v, right[k]].every { it instanceof Map }
                     ? [k, merge(v, right[k])]
                     : [k, right[k]] // this is where you define the actual merge behavior 
                                     // in this case: righ precedes left
             }
    ].collectMany { Map it -> it.entrySet() }.collectEntries()
}
```

This method not only processes more deeply nested maps, but also takes care of keys that are only in one of the maps. I've seen many solutions fail if the nested structures aren't the same for both maps. Here are some test cases

```
assert merge([a:1], [a:2]) == [a:2]
assert merge([a:[b:1]], [a:2]) == [a:2]
assert merge([a:[b:1], c:1], [a:[b:2], c:2]) == [a:[b:2], c:2]
assert merge([a:1], [b:2]) == [a:1, b:2]
assert merge([a:[b:[c:[d:1]]]], [a:[b:[c:[e:2]]]]) == [a:[b:[c:[d:1, e:2]]]]
```